# Collect Cloudwatch metrics and upload to S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am trying to understand this below shell script in online blog, could someone please explain me what actual happening this I really don't understand what is this means (if [[ $# -lt 2 ]]; then)

The execution command which they provide is here:
/path/collect_cw_metrics.sh <Destination_AWS_Account ID> <S3_Bucket_AWS_Account_ID> [<AWS_Region>]

**The Shell scripts here:**
**Wrapper script – collect_cw_metrics.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
if [[ $# -lt 2 ]]; then
  echo "Usage: ${0} <AccountID> <S3_Bucket_AccountID>"
  exit 1
fi
NOW=$(date +"%m%d%Y%H%M")
AccontID=${1}
s3_AccountID=${2}
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=${3} ## 3rd Argument is the Account Default Region is diff than the CLI server
csvfile=/tmp/cw-${AccontID}-${NOW}.csv
#
## Reset Env variables
reset_env () {
        unset AWS_SESSION_TOKEN
        unset AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
        unset AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
        unset AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
} #end of reset_env
## Set Env function
assume_role () {
AccontID=${1}
source </path_to_source_env_file/filename> ${AccontID}
}
# Function assume_role ends
assume_role ${AccontID}
if [[ ! -z "$3" ]]; then
        AWS_DEFAULT_REGION='us-east-2'
fi
#
## Generate CSV file
python <path_of_the_script>/collect_cw_metrics.py ${AccontID} ${csvfile}
##
## Upload generated CSV file to S3
reset_env
assume_role ${s3_AccountID}
echo ${csvfile}
echo "Uploading data file  to S3...."
aws s3 cp ${csvfile} <Bucket_Name>
reset_env
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume this script is used for collection metrics in a centralized account. This means that we can have a bunch of accounts which send metrics (`.csv` files) to an S3 bucket which is situated in another account.

`$#` refers to the number of arguments which are passed to script when it is executed. Since the script has 2 mandatory arguments, `if [[ $# -lt 2 ]]` validates that this arguments are actually provided.

If I understand correctly, these 2 arguments are:
`Destination_AWS_Account ID` - the account number which runs the EC2 instances (I assume) on which you run this script
`S3_Bucket_AWS_Account_ID` - the account number which has the S3 bucket where the metrics are uploaded

The third argument is optional, it is `us-east-2` or what you pass to the script.